# Can't change touchpad to left handed

Tags: mouse, trackpad

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and when I try to change the mouse from right to left handed via the GUI, nothing happens. I tried using `xinput set-button-map 11 3 2 1` to change it manually, which worked for the buttons, but it made tapping my trackpad trigger the secondary button. Please help :)

Comment: Try changing it manually: `gsettings set  org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse left-handed "true"
` does that work?

Comment: Thanks Seth, no, that doesn't work.

Comment: What desktop environment/distro are you using? Is this a fresh install or did you upgrade to get here?

Comment: It's a fresh install. I downloaded 13.10, 64-bit yesterday.